# Laravel installation problems with old PHP CLI version

Tags: php, laravel

I want to install Laravel 5.2.31, but my PHP CLI version is only 5.3.3 instead of >= 5.5.9 and I got the following error:

```
# composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.2.31 la1

[InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 5.2.31 in a version  installable using your PHP version 5.3.3.
```

Comment: You can't install Laravel 5 on that version of PHP :(

Comment: shouldn't intall anything on that PHP version.

Comment: yes, i know but i cant change the php cli because of plesk and php by os vendor, i have installed php 5.6.30 and 7.1 also on the server, but only with phpinfo()

Comment: what about this export PATH=/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin:$PATH; php composer.phar update

Comment: try using --ignore-platform-reqs on composer in this case

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to make sure the PHP >= 5.5.9 is used. Depending on the environment it works differently.

In Ubuntu environment it is possible to use `https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives`

`which php` tells you which PHP binary is used right now and you need to make sure that this binary is of PHP >= 5.5.9